# Proxying SOAP services with REST - Sharing generated SEI's

Tags: java, spring, rest, soap, apache-camel

I have a few SOAP webservices I need to proxy with a REST frontend. REST API operations would map 1-1 to their SOAP equivalents.

For instance for invoking operation `operation1` for the SOAP webservice at http://soapservices/ServiceA its REST proxy would be POST http://restservices/ServiceA/operation1, with the same exact data binding objects for arguments and return value.

I'll use Camel to dynamically route REST invocations to their corresponding SOAP endpoints, and possibly perform some common pre or post processing.

Ideally I'd like to have a project where I just add the proxied WSDL's, have the JAX-WS Service Endpoint Interfaces generated with Maven's `cxf-codegen-plugin`, and dynamically instance `CxfEndpoint` beans for the services using a properties file that will enumerate them.

For the JAX-RS part, I've found reusing the generated SEI's to be quite convenient, and have used a `SpringJAXRSServerFactoryBean` that gets its `resourceClasses` set programmatically at application startup, reading enumerated services from the same properties file.

I've got a working draft project, but having to manually change the generated SEI's to add JAX-RS annotations (`@Path`, `@Consumes`, `@Produces`, `@Post` and so on) looks just bad.

For instance:

For this, and N in general generated SEI's like this one:

```
@WebService(...)
@XmlSeeAlso(...)
@SoapBinding(...)
public interface ServiceAPortType { 
    @WebMethod(operationName="operation1")
    @WebResult(...)
    public ResponseObject operation1(@WebParam(...) ParamObject param);
}
```

I have a yml file:

```
services: 
   - service: ServiceA
     config: 
        address: http://soapservices/ServiceA
        serviceClass: ServiceAPortType.class
   - service: ServiceB
     config: 
        address: http://soapservices/ServiceB
        serviceClass: ServiceBPortType.class
```

Then register `CxfEndpoint`s for the clients:

```
@PostConstruct
public void registerSOAPClients(){
    Map<String, Object> values = (Map<String, Object>) ws.getConfig(); // "ws" injected with @ConfigurationProperties
    BeanDefinitionBuilder bdb = BeanDefinitionBuilder.rootBeanDefinition(CxfEndpoint.class);
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> val : values.entrySet()) {
        bdb.addPropertyValue(val.getKey(), val.getValue());
    }
    beanFactory.registerBeanDefinition(ws.getService(), bdb.getBeanDefinition());
}
```

The JAX-RS part is the one that needs manual tweaking of the generated SEI's to add `@Path`, `@Consumes` and various annotations to let `SpringJAXRSServerFactoryBean` use them:

```
@Bean
public SpringJAXRSServerFactoryBean jaxRSfactoryBean() throws ClassNotFoundException { 
    SpringJAXRSServerFactoryBean bean = new SpringJAXRSServerFactoryBean();
    bean.setAddress("/restservices");
    bean.setResourceClasses(jaxRSAnnotatedSEIs); // jaxRSAnnotatedSEIs injected from yml serviceClass
    return bean;
}
```

The Camel route is pretty simple and along the lines of:

```
from("cxfrs:bean:jaxRSfactoryBean?providers=#jsonProvider")
.setHeader("serviceName", getServiceFromURI())
.setHeader("operationName", getOperationFromURI())
.toD("cxf:bean:${header.serviceName}Service?")
.transform().simple("${body.get(0)}")
.marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)
.end();
```

Is there any way I could automate adding these annotations so generated source stays unedited, or generating JAX-RS SEI's from a SOAP WSDL or the existing JAX-WS SEIs? Or maybe there is a different cleaner approach? I'm open to alternative approaches as long as they don't involve manual modifications of generated sources and rely on properties files only for enumerating and configuring services.

Comment: One option I've found that may suit as a solution is extending the generated interface, overriding all methods and placing the JAX-RS annotations there. This way the REST service API stays tightly coupled to the original SOAP contract and the generated interface, and is also a way to provide a mapping for REST resources and methods to their SOAP equivalents. Also a good place to place swagger annotations and generate API docs later.